# Custom object status is not found Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have CRD definition in Kubernetes. When I try to send a request with `kubectl proxy` by this link:

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/
```

I get created custom object information. However, when I try to get the status of this custom object with:

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/status
```

I get an error:

```
 {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io \"status\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "status",
    "group": "sparkoperator.k8s.io",
    "kind": "sparkapplications"
  },
  "code": 404
```

Why there is no status for the custom object? Is there something wrong with CRD definition?

I use Minikube version v0.32.0 which I start this way:

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.13.0 --memory 8048 --cpus 3 --feature-gates=CustomResourceSubresources=true
```

CRD definition looks like this:

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-example
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Scala
  image: gcr.io/ynli-k8s/spark:v2.4.0-SNAPSHOT
  mainClass: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkExample
  mainApplicationFile: http://localhost:8089/spark_k8s_airflow.jar
  mode: cluster
  deps: {}
  driver:
    coreLimit: 1000m
    cores: 0.1
    labels:
      version: 2.4.0
    memory: 1024m
    serviceAccount: default
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    labels:
      version: 2.4.0
    memory: 1024m
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  subresources:
    status: {}
```

UPDATE: I have called the object spark-example specifically, the object data is returned, but the status call returns error.

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/spark-example/status
```

returns this message:

```
the server could not find the requested resource
```

Although, there is subresources definition in the CRD definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/
```

The above request will give you the list of `SparkApplication` kind objects in `default` namespaces.

To get specific object, you have to specify the object name:

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/<object-name>
```

`status` is the part of the object, not `SparkApplication` kind. That's why you are getting that error. If you try for specific object, it will work.

```
curl http://localhost:8090/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/<object-name>/status
```

> Note: I am assuming that you enabled `status` subresource for `SparkApplication` CRD. Otherwise it will give error.

If `status` subresource is not enabled in CRD definition, then you can not get status in `/status` subpath. This is the feature of **subresource**.

How to know whether `status` subresource enabled or not:

Check CRD yaml:

```
$ kubectl get crds/foos.try.com -o yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: foos.try.com
spec:
  group: try.com
  version: v1alpha1
  scope: Namespaced
  subresources:
    status: {}
  names:
    plural: foos
    singular: foo
    kind: Foo
```

If CRD has following field under `spec`, then `status` subresource is enabled.

```
subresources:
  status: {}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. However, I get `the server could not find the requested resource` error anyway

Comment: Check whether you enabled `status` subresource in the CRD definition. If it is not enabled, then you will get error.

Comment: Well, I have defined status subresource in SparkApplication definition. I am not sure that I can edit crd as I have built it from the official Dockerfile.

Comment: Looks like the "sparkapplications.sparkoperator.k8s.io" CRD does not include this 'status' field in its original definition (manifest file), here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/manifest/spark-operator-crds.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the post in 2019. I come from another question when StatusWriter always failed to update CRD obj status and your post reminded me to check status subresource kubebuilder marker.